# What does "Migration" means?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, private-blockchain, migration

I saw different companies like [Goldmint](https://www.goldmint.io/tokens) have on their roadmap this step **"Migration to owned blockchain"**.

Could anyone explain **how a "Migration" works from Ethereum to a private blockchain** and what happens to all tokens already present on Ethereum (because are also exchanged)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I saw in solitidy code, migration part is a built-in piece of code that let the owner update the contract address.

Migration to a private blockchain may also involve a private or custom ethereum network.